# Android Gradle: Custom Plugin with id 'XXXX' not found - Kotlin DSL

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to develop a gradle plugin to use it for generating some objects and methods for our api using some scheme.
I have followed some tutorials but they all seem not to work, atleast for me.
Some of these tutorials were:

1. https://musings.animus.design/kotlin-poet-building-a-gradle-plugin/
2. https://medium.com/@magicbluepenguin/how-to-create-your-first-custom-gradle-plugin-efc1333d4419

I have not used the buildSrc module because I'm already using it for Kotlin DSL, so I decided to create a new module and create my plugin there.

My plugin's module `build.gradle.kts` looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id("java-gradle-plugin")
    id("kotlin")
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath(config.ClassPaths.androidBuildTools)
        classpath(config.ClassPaths.kotlinGradlePlugin)
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(config.ClassPaths.androidBuildTools)
    implementation(config.ClassPaths.kotlinGradlePlugin)
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("Generator") {
            id = "Generator"
            implementationClass = "Generator"
        }
    }
}
```

My projects `settings.gradle.kts` looks like this:

```
include(":SampleProject", ":scheme-generator")
```

And in my application module's `build.gradle.kts` I'm applying this plugin like this:

```
apply(plugin = "Generator")
```

The build script stops here with an error: plugin 'Generator' not found

My Generator class looks like this:

```
class Generator : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        target.android().variants().all { variant ->

            // Make a task for each combination of build type and product flavor
            val myTask = "myFirstTask${variant.name.capitalize()}"

            // Register a simple task as a lambda. We can later move this to its own
            // class to make our code cleaner and also add some niceties.
            target.tasks.create(myTask){task ->

                // Group all our plugin's tasks together
                task.group = "MyPluginTasks"
                task.doLast {
                    File("${target.projectDir.path}/myFirstGeneratedFile.txt").apply {
                        writeText("Hello Gradle!\nPrinted at: ${SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(Date())}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `android` and `variants` methods are declared in a utils file, they look like this:

```
object GeneratorUtils {

    fun Project.android(): BaseExtension {
        val android = project.extensions.findByType(BaseExtension::class.java)
        if (android != null) {
            return android
        } else {
            throw GradleException("Project $name is not an Android project")
        }
    }

    fun BaseExtension.variants(): DomainObjectSet<out BaseVariant> {
        return when (this) {
            is AppExtension -> {
                applicationVariants
            }

            is LibraryExtension -> {
                libraryVariants
            }

            else -> throw GradleException("Unsupported BaseExtension type!")
        }
    }

}
```

I have tried many things, but I seem not to get this right.

**EDIT:**
Using the buildSrc module for my plugin works totally fine, the plugin is applied and the gradle tasks are visible. However, buildSrc is reserved for other purposes, and we would like our plugin to be in a separate module, so we will be able to use it in other projects.

**EDIT 13/04/2021**

I have managed to see the tasks that are added by my plugin in my app tasks list by including this module as a composite build.

My `settings.gradle` now looks like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("generator")
}

include(":SampleProject")
```

`build.gradle` of my plugin looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java-gradle-plugin' // Allows us to create and configure custom plugins
apply plugin: 'kotlin' //Needed as we'll write our plugin in Kotlin

buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.4.31'
        gradle_version = '4.1.2'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$gradle_version"
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // Android gradle plugin will allow us to access Android specific features
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("Generator") {
            id = "Generator"
            implementationClass = "com.example.Generator"
        }
    }
}
```

And my generator class now looks like this:

```
class Generator : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {

        project.tasks.register("generationTask") { task ->
            task.apply {
                group = "generation"
                actions.add(Action {
                    print("Hello from generation task!")
                })
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I can see `generationTask` in my tasks list and I can execute it normally. It prints the text without any problems.

The problem now is to include `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2` in my dependecies to use it to access build types and flavors and their paths to save my generated code there. When I add it to my dependencies block, gradle fails with this error:  `Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2.`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Gradle build goes through specific [set of phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html), and the Configuration phase comes before the Execution phase. So you cannot use a plugin, which is built in the same build process, because by the time gradle tries to use it on Configuration phase, the plugin has not been built yet.

`buildSrc` directory is a special one, it's built not as part of the same build process, but in a separate build, before the main build process starts. This feature is called [included or composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html#composite_build_intro). `buildSrc` is just a pre-defined way to set up a composite build and you can define your own included builds. So to make your plugin visible to the main build, you need to put it into a separate build and include this build into a composite build as described in the doc above. [Here](https://medium.com/bumble-tech/how-to-use-composite-builds-as-a-replacement-of-buildsrc-in-gradle-64ff99344b58) is an article describing how to transform a plugin defined in `buildSrc` into a composite build.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have faced the article describing how to move from buildSrc to composite builds. It works If I'm willing to use Kotlin DSL, but in my case, I need to write my plugin in Kotlin JVM to and use android build tools features. I have tried to define class paths and dependencies inside the gradle.build file of that separate module but it didn't help, It cannot find plugin Kotlin JVM or Kotlin Android. Any suggestions?

Comment: I will grant the bounty since you added some useful resources and there's no other answer that contains any useful information. But I would be grateful if we continue this discussion and find a solution.

Comment: Did it work on buildSrc? I don't see a reason for the configuration of the separate module to be different from the buildSrc configuration. If you rely on the mentioned plugins in your plugin, make sure you add them as dependencies, not as buildscript classpath.

Comment: It worked, but our buildSrc is reserved for build configs using Kotlin DSL. I need to use Kotlin JVM in my plugin, and we can't include both Kotlin DSL and JVM together in one module. Also, a separate module is preferred, so that we can reuse this plugin in multiple projects. Any Ideas?

Comment: I have managed to include a separate module as an includedBuild inside pluginManagement in settings.gradle file. I removed android build tools dependency and the code that's shown above and registered a simple task in the apply method of the plugin. I can see these tasks in my app tasks and that's what I was looking for. But I also need android build tools because I will be using this plugin to generate code for different build variants using Kotlin poet. adding android tools dependency to dependencies block fails the build with an error that it cannot resolve this dependency.

Comment: I will edit the question with my new code.

Comment: @TamimAttafi I tried to replicate your code and had no issue adding the `com.android.tools.build:gradle` dependency. Can you post full error message when you build from terminal?

Comment: It doesn't write any errors anymore, but my app module no longer builds when I add this line to dependecies: dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
}
If I remove it then I can build my project normally.
Now I can normally generate code through a separate module, but I can't see the generated code from my code if I don't add its path explicitly to java.srcDirs from my app build.gradle even if it is under build/generated/source folder. Is there a solution without srcDirs and android gradle plugin? Could we move to telegram? I can send code there.